# wpf - Secure role based login

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I would like to implement a role based login into my application however I'm not sure where to start. I've read on similar questions where, because PasswordBox can't have bindings, things get complicated. The solutions that were offered don't really fit into my requirements.

I have a database where usernames and passwords are stored (in plain text, I know that's not secure), and currently do logging in by using SqlDataReader and find the matching Username and Password entered.

While this does work, it is quite slow and not very secure.

How can I have speedier logins, save passwords more securely and then retrieve the username and role of the person currently logged in so I can display it in a TextBlock?

And if logging in does take a while no matter the approach, how could I display a message letting the user know it's doing just that?

**UPDATE:** 
 Let's forget about making it speedier for now, how can I go about making it more secure and do logins in the background so it doesn't freeze up the UI? And would MVVM still be the best approach, even though PasswordBox is not bindable?

Comment: You're entrusting a user with access to your website, security is your number 1 concern, far above speed...i would rather have a user take 1h to login than have free reign on a database

Comment: @BernardWalters You're right, good point

Comment: What credentials do you use to access the database from within your app? Integrated Security?

Comment: @Ehssan Yes, that would be Windows Authentication I believe

Comment: @bruh1234 In that case, why don't you just rely on Windows Authentication?

Comment: @Ehssan I'm currently creating it for a single company so that would make sense, but should in case I want to provide it to other companies in the future and they need different login rights, it would be great if I have it implemented from now.

Comment: @Ehssan How about this, when the user starts the application, it detects the currently logged in windows user (displays their username) and asks for their password which they use to login to windows. Can that be done?

Comment: Yes of course, that can be done. But to what end? The user already signed in using bis credentials, so he is already authenticated. What you should care about is how to authorize the user. What are the actions/ resources that you want to protect in the app, and what are the authorization rules (e.g. all users of a certain age) that determine what the user is allowed to do?

Comment: @Ehssan While it is true that the user is already authenticated, in a scenario where they left their computer open and someone tried accessing the app, prompting them to login to the app would prevent any unwanted snoopers.